# how to add video on another video as overlay

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, video, avfoundation

I am stuck on overlay video into another video, as I successfully add video on another video but not able to make scale same for both videos. taking reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270719/objective-c-how-to-add-overlay-to-video-using-avfoundation).

**note: I have to add overlay video with transparency so below video visible.**

Comment: Hey! Did you solve this?